# Converting 5V Square-Wave to +-5V Square-Wave

Tags: arduino, high-frequency, square, signal-conversion

I am a student electronic engineer and was hoping to get some guidance on a project that I am working on. I am using the [AD9850 module](https://components101.com/modules/ad9850-dds-signal-generator-module) to output a 5V square-wave at 1.1MHz as can be seen in the figure below:

[image: oscilloscope]

I was wondering if it is possible to somehow convert this square-wave into a +/-5V (10Vpp) square wave at 1.1MHz frequency. Is it possible to achieve this with just a 5V power supply or would an external power supply of 10V be required? The signal is to be used to excite an ultrasonic transducer.

Comment: You could use an RF 1:2 step-up transformer or, you could use an amplifier with appropriate supply voltage(s).

Comment: The best design will have specs for all assumptions on frequency error, power output and impedance of load.  Then decide how to drive a large capacitive load with a low impedance by appropriate push pull driver keep in mind/simulate Q, L, C, R with a differential output.  SHow tolerances with all specs.

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqUD5y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Seems that using AD9850 to generate your square wave could be done with a simpler numerically controlled oscillator.
Those two NOT gates would be driven with a 5V DC supply voltage. HCMOS gates like 74HC04 would have approximately 50 ohm drive impedance (each). Parallel connection of unused gates to **NOT1** and to **NOT2** increases drive available.
If you *still* need more drive, Justme's method of H-bridge drive would be more appropriate, and would also result in 10V p-p available.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would this method have the square wave swinging from +5V to -5V resulting in 10V peak to peak?

Comment: Actually in my answer I did have a H bridge made of inverters in mind, just like in your answer. But it's now deleted because apparently it did not answer the question. I guess it was too short.

Comment: Yes, the voltage available at the ultrasonic terminals would be 10V peak-to-peak. You haven't mentioned ultrasonic impedance @ 1.1MHz. It is possible that 1.1MHz current flowing through the transducer will *load down* those two NOTgate drivers, reducing the 10V p-p to something less. The 6 NOT gates inside 74HC04 could be paralleled into 2 ranks to help this potential problem (schematic reivsed). Note that a transducer with one terminal grounded cannot use this solution.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Instead of solving OP's question, you solved OP's problem. Engineering at its best!